# Swift indexPathForSelectedRow returns nil from subview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift4

I have a subview with a table and I'm populating the data just fine. I have the "prepare(for segue:" from the superview recognizing the selection of the cell just fine. However, from the prepare function in the super the indexPathForSelectedRow returns nil. Even though I have the cell selected.

```
self.crossRefTVC.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow //returns nil
```

Everything else works fine, including populating crossRefTVC.tableview data from the main superview.

Adding this detail:

```
class MyText: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var crossRefTable: UITableView!
    var crossRefTVC = CrossRefTVC()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        crossRefTable.delegate = crossRefTVC
        crossRefTable.dataSource = crossRefTVC
    }

    @objc func myMethodToHandleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            crossRefTVC.results.append(data)
            crossRefView.center = view.center
            view.addSubview(crossRefView)
    }
...
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "CRShowDetail" {
            print(self.crossRefTVC.tableView)
            print(self.crossRefTVC.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as Any)

        }
    }

class CrossRefTVC : UITableViewController {

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      //other table overrided funcs here, all work.
}
```

like I said, the prepare code executes correctly, and it can access the variables in crossRefTVC, but it can't see the selected cell for some reason.

You can see the storyboard for this subview here:

[image]

Comment: can you illustrate the structure in a better way ?

Comment: I've added some more of the code as an example of what I'm doing

Comment: It seems likely that `self.crossRefTVC` is referring to a different instance of your `CrossRefTVC` class - How do you display the contained `CrossRefTVC` instance?

Comment: I just added the myMethodToHandleTap function. That's how I add the subview. I'm not creating any other instance of crossRefTVC

Comment: But how does `crossRefView` relate to `crossRefTVC`?

Comment: I don't think I have any direct link between the two. crossRefView is linked from the storyboard by ctl-clicking and dragging to the MyText class.

Comment: I set the results array in crossRefTVC in the myMethodToHandleTap, which is what the CrossRefTVC class uses to populate the table data

Comment: Right. That is the problem. Your table view is coming from a scene instantiated from a storyboard while you are just using a plain initialiser to set `crossRefTVC` so that property is unrelated to the table view that is on screen.  Why don’t you use the `crossRefTable` property that you already have?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I do that? Like you say, crossRefTable comes from the storyboard, so how do I tell it's of a type of CrossRefTVC?

Comment: How are you creating that view controller? Is it in a container view?

Comment: at the start of the MyText class I just do a: var crossRefTVC = CrossRefTVC()

Comment: Yes, but that doesn’t put the table view on screen. It just creates an instance of that view controller class.  How does the table view that you are interacting with get on screen?

Comment: The table is in the subview (pictured above). That links to crossRefTable in the MyText class. I set the crossRefTable delegate and datasource to crossRefTVC. Then I add crossRefView as a subview to the view of MyText

Comment: Where do you add the Subview?  How?  Are you using a container view with an embed segue?  If you are then you can get the reference to the embedded view controller in prepareForSegue for the embed segue

Comment: You can see it in the above code in the myMethodToHandleTap function. It's called when tapping on a uitextview in MyText

Comment: But that is `crossRefView`, not `crossRefTVC`. Where did `crossRefView` come from?  That property doesn’t seem to be related to the `CrossRefTVC` instance you have created and assigned to `crossRefTVC`.  It seems like you just need to remove the `crossRefTVC` property and just use `crossRefView`

Comment: crossRefView comes from this like at the top of MyText class: @IBOutlet var crossRefTable: UITableView! Sorry I'm kinda new to this, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: If I use crossRefView, it is a generic UITableView, with no knowledge of my array that I use to populate the data of that. Nor does it have awareness of the code I use to set the row text cell for each entry of that data array. I'm not sure how I get crossRefView to do that.

Comment: I actually removed crossRefTVC and added UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate to MyText class, and just used that for all the table related code. This solved the issue. Though I didn't really want to have all the code in this main class, but at least it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed crossRefTVC and added UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate to MyText class, and just used that for all the table related code. This solved the issue. Though I didn't really want to have all the code in this main class, but at least it works now. Thanks